# How to get accurate altitude above mean sea level with NASA's EGM96.java?

Tags: java, geolocation, altitude

The EGM96.java always throws an IO exception when I try to run it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    EGM96 egm = new EGM96("config/EGM96.dat");
    LatLon latlon = LatLon.fromDegrees(1.4, 103.9);
    double offset = egm.getOffset(latlon.getLatitude(),latlon.getLatitude());
}
```

This will cause an IO exception.

However, the IO exceptions dissapears when

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    EGM96 egm = new EGM96("config/EGM96.dat");
    LatLon latlon = LatLon.fromDegrees(1.4, 103.9);
    double offset = egm.getOffset(latlon.getLatitude(),latlon.getLatitude());
    double offset = egm.getOffset(latlon.getLatitude(),latlon.getLatitude());
}
```

But I cannot have 2 variables of the same name. If I tried to change one of the variable, the IO exception comes back.

EGM96.java is available at http://worldwind31.arc.nasa.gov/svn/trunk/WorldWind/src/gov/nasa/worldwind/util/EGM96.java

Comment: did you put the `EMG96.dat` file inside the config directory?

Comment: Yes, I did. "config/EGM96.dat" @guido

Comment: When you said 'This will cause an IO exception' do you mean you get the exception stack trace when the code is run? And again, you said the exception disappears when you declare offset twice. This code (the one that fixes the IO ex) wouldn't even compile. Are you sure you are getting the exception thrown when the code is run and not the compiler error?

Comment: @prabugp it's compiler error

Comment: that class you found at NASA is among the most crappy pieces of code i ever seen!

Comment: @guido Any other suggestions for this kind of code for geoid height?

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting a compiler error, it means that the EGM code could potentially throw the exception at runtime and you should be handling that. This is usually done with a try-catch block where you'd catch the exception and print an error message or do some other custom processing. Please check [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions) for details on how this whole thing works.

Comment: The EGM constructor: public EGM96(String offsetsFilePath) throws IOException. Looks like it's purposely throwing it?

Comment: So... any problem in handling that? Can you just try catching it or re-throwing and run the application at least once to see how that works for you? We can work with a error stack trace way better than working on compiler errors.